# MySQL / PHP/ Javascript - Apostrophe in echoed text causing errors

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm currently making a graph using mysql/php/javascript/googlecharts.

My 't_text' column however keeps escaping when I'm echoing it out in Javascript in Google Charts.
Where do I need to put in a real escape string to fix this issue?

```
Example of Problem:
Tweet 1) "He'll be the last one there"
Tweet 2) "It's her pen"
```

Solution would be ignoring the ' (apostrophe) with a mysqli_real_escape_string statement but I don't know to implement it

```
<?php

  $tablequery = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT handle,t_text, t_date,t_time,sentiment, score FROM tweets ");

  while ($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($tablequery))
  {
    $handle = $r["handle"];
    $t_text= $r["t_text"];
    $t_date= $r["t_date"];
    $t_time= $r["t_time"];
    $sentiment = $r["sentiment"];
    $score= $r["score"];
    $tablechart[] = "['".$handle."','".$t_text."','".$t_date."','".$t_time."','".$sentiment. "','".$score."']";
  }
?>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["table"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

  function drawTable() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'User');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Text');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Time');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Sentiment');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Score');

    data.addRows([
      <?php echo(implode(",",$tablechart));?>
    ]);

    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

    table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true});
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You have to escape your text before inserting it into the query. If you don't escape, not only you get errors, but you are also vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Do not *remove* the *single quotes*, but *escape* them. Also *back ticks* are not the same as *single quotes*

Comment: Thanks Lorenz - So if I escape the random text won't matter?

Comment: Where do I place the escape string then?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer: The Python code *takes care of escaping*, because the OP is using SQL parameters correctly. You really want to leave that to the database adapter and not do this yourself.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks. I'm just beginner in Python. You have to help out the OP here.

Comment: What actual problems are you experiencing here? You are already using SQL parameters, single quotes in the input text are *not a problem*; the database adapter takes care of this all for you.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer: right, which is why I am pointing out that escaping is the wrong thing to do here. I am surprised the OP thinks it is needed.

Comment: You need to fix *your Javascript code*. How are you using the data coming from the database?

Comment: My problem is that I'm inserting the data in correctly but when I'm echoing it out in Google charts it doesn't escape. Do you know where I should put it? $tablequery = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT handle,t_text, t_date,t_time,sentiment, score FROM tweets ");  <-- I then run a while loop to iterate through the column of t_text

Comment: @Zachary: please update your question to show how you are using the data from the database; trying to 'fix' the data when inserting is entirely the wrong thing to do here.

Comment: <?php

      $tablequery = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT handle,t_text, t_date,t_time,sentiment, score FROM tweets ");

      while ($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($tablequery))
      {
        $handle = $r["handle"];
        $t_text= $r["t_text"];
        $t_date= $r["t_date"];
        $t_time= $r["t_time"];
        $sentiment = $r["sentiment"];
        $score= $r["score"];
        $tablechart[] = "['".$handle."','".$t_text."','".$t_date."','".$t_time."','".$sentiment. "','".$score."']";
      }
    ?>

Comment: @Zachary: so you have a PHP / JavaScript problem here, not a Python or MySQL problem. [Edit] your question and tags accordingly.

Comment: Collect your data in a regular array and try `json_encode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem, this is not an issue of SQL queries breaking on insertion to the DB, rather data output to JavaScript is breaking your JavaScript?

If so, this is not an issue for which you need to  use add_slashes or DB-layer escape methods (such as `mysqli_real_escape_string`).

*Never* try to build a data structure for one language in another language by "writing" code in strings if there is a data serialization scheme available. In this case, JSON is perfect.

**So, simply build a PHP data structure with the data you desire:**

```
// takes $r and makes an indexed array of the values, then adds it to $tablechart
$tablechart[] = array_values($r);

// if $r holds more than you want to send, you could weed it out some:
$tablechart[] = array(
    $r["handle"],
    $r["t_text"],
    $r["t_date"],
    $r["t_time"],
    $r["sentiment"],
    $r["score"]
);
```

**Then, use this to output to your JS instead:**

```
data.addRows(<?php echo(json_encode($tablechart);?>);
```

The PHP function, [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), serializes the PHP data into JSON. JSON can be directly outputted into JavaScript as it uses a subset of the JavaScript literal syntax.

Always remember your "code boundaries"--that is, *"where am I and what data do I have, and where is it going from here?"* Having figured that out, determine what the appropriate data-prep methods are for the data's destination and use it. In this case you need to get a PHP data structure into JS. JSON and PHP's `json_encode` were designed for this sort of thing.

**Those suggestions having been made, here is how I would personally refactor what you posted:**

```
<?php
    $tablequery = mysqli_query($dbc,'SELECT handle, t_text, t_date, t_time, sentiment, score FROM tweets');

    $tablechart = array();

    // using mysqli_fetch_row to get indexed array since that's what the JS was wanting
    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_row($tablequery)) {
        $tablechart[] = $r;
    }
?>

<script>
    (function (scope, tablechart) {
        'use strict';

        var document = scope.document,
            google = scope.google;

        google.load('visualization', '1', {
            packages: ['table']
        });

        google.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(),
                table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

            data.addColumn('string', 'User');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Text');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Time');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Sentiment');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Score');

            data.addRows(tablechart);

            table.draw(data, {
                showRowNumber: true
            });
        });
    }(
        this,
        <?= json_encode($tablechart) ?>
    ));
</script>
```